# Unable to use Allennlp biaffine parser model

Tags: nlp, pytorch, dependency-parsing, allennlp

I am trying to use allennlp predictor for biaffine parser. Here is the code:-

```
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
predictor = Predictor.from_path("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/biaffine-dependency-parser-ptb-2018.08.23.tar.gz")
```

However, I get this error:-

```
ConfigurationError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-74e2bcfcbf43> in <module>()
      1 from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
----> 2 predictor = Predictor.from_path("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/biaffine-dependency-parser-ptb-2018.08.23.tar.gz")

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/allennlp/common/params.py in pop_choice(self, key, choices, default_to_first_choice, allow_class_names)
    350                 """{"model": "my_module.models.MyModel"} to have it imported automatically."""
    351             )
--> 352             raise ConfigurationError(message)
    353         return value
    354 

ConfigurationError: universal_dependencies not in acceptable choices for dataset_reader.type: ['conll2003', 'interleaving', 'sequence_tagging', 'sharded', 'babi', 'text_classification_json']. You should either use the --include-package flag to make sure the correct module is loaded, or use a fully qualified class name in your config file like {"model": "my_module.models.MyModel"} to have it imported automatically.
```

Comment: Where did you find the link to that model? I'm just curious because it's so old.

Comment: @petew , just trying to reproduce some results of a research paper. They had used the older version of the parser in their code.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, if you really need to use that exact model, you'll have to find use an older version of AllenNLP. Unfortunately I can't tell you which version would work off the top of my head. But v0.9.0 might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very old model, the newer version should work fine: https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/biaffine-dependency-parser-ptb-2020.04.06.tar.gz